# No enclosing instance of type MainActivity is accessible?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-context

I've got a Fragment containing it's own layout. This layout has a ListView.
Now I've tried to add an adapter for this ListView like this:

```
public static class LatestFragment extends Fragment {
    ListView listView;
    String[] values = {
            "Test", "Test2"
    };

    public LatestFragment() {

    }
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_latest, container, false);
        listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_latest_listview1);
        listView.setAdapter(new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), values));
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

But I keep getting an error at

```
new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), values)
```

Eclipse tells me following:

```
No enclosing instance of type MainActivity is accessible. Must qualify the
allocation with an enclosing instance of type MainActivity (e.g. x.new A() 
where x is an instance of MainActivity).
```

Why can't I set up an adapter for my ListView?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that `CustomListAdapter` is not defined as a `static` inner class, and therefore it cannot be used from another `static` inner class.

Also, please get rid of the constructor, or at least chain to the superclass constructor.